# Is there a standard approach to rolling out database schema changes?

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

A developer said I should simply wrap all my database upgrade scripts in a transaction.  If it fails, just roll back all changes.  All my instincts tell me this is wrong, especially when it comes to dealing with large volumes of data and/or procedures and functions.

I typically hand-hold the upgrade process on single instance databases as follows:

- Negotiate a maintenance window
- Prepare upgrade scripts
- Put database into restricted user mode
- Disable scheduled jobs/processes that would normally hit the database
  during this window
- Perform a full backup
- Apply the upgrade scripts
- Have developer or test team confirm the app operates as expected
- Put database back into multi-user mode
- Release the database for normal use

When it comes to rolling out changes to several hundred instances, however, I have changed my process as follows:

- I make the upgrade scripts much more robust: they can be run multiple times on the same server without harm, database version numbers are repected, scripts will terminate if they are run against the run version, etc.
- spawn a process for each server (using powershell, osql, etc)
- run the appropriate upgrade script
- report success or failure

Comment: A recently related question (and yes, I posted an answer to it): http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/144162/13156 And I'm pretty sure I've seen it asked on http://www.Stackoverflow.com, but I don't have time to search it.

Comment: I didn't search programmers first, because this is a database administrative question. Your answer there didn't include any more information that I already had in my own question.  thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no standard process because every system is different.  About the last thing that I would do if just wrap everything in a single transaction.  What happens if I need to move 500 Gigs of data around?  That's one massive transaction.

Recently I've been using database snapshots as my rollback.

Basically take a snapshot, make the changes.  Delete the snapshot after signoff.  If upgrade failed roll back the snapshot and then try again.

It's a lot quicker to roll back a snapshot than to restore the database (assuming that the database is large).